# How to make push notification with startActivity function (like Google Calendar Push Notifications on LockScreen)

Tags: android

How to make push notification with `startActivity` function (like Google Calendar Push Notifications on LockScreen)
I can't make push notification with activity lock screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot and shouldn't `startActivity` directly. Use `sendBroadcast` flow and define `intent-filter` for your specific activity that handles the action:

Example:

In Notification service class:

```
val broadcastIntent = Intent("com.example.foo.bar.YOUR_ACTION")
broadcastIntent.putExtra("ParameterKey", parameterObject)
sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent)
```

In Manifest, define `inetnt-filter` for your receiver activity to catch the action and start itself:

```
<activity
    android:name=".ReceiverActivity" >  
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.foo.bar.YOUR_ACTION" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```